# List of Chess Informant symbols that can be used in our PGN viewer?

Tags: discussion, pgn-viewer

Can someone post a list of Chess Informant ( and other symbols if any ) that can be used in our PGN viewer?

It is very useful to use them instead of commentary to preserve space. There were few bugs I encountered when using them, so I use this opportunity to point that out so it can be fixed in the near future, hopefully.

Posting an example game with all of the symbols in it is OK as well.

Thank you. Best regards.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Almost all of the informant symbols are supported, but you have to use the NAG format for them (a dollar sign and then a number corresponding to the symbol).

Here's a list of all of the symbols that are included:

```
$1   !
$2   ?
$3   !!
$4   ??
$5   !?
$6   ?!
$7   □ (only move)
$10  =
$13  ∞ (unclear)
$14  +/= (white slightly better)
$15  =/+ (black slightly better)
$16  +/- (white moderately better)
$17  -/+ (black moderately better)
$18  +- (white is winning)
$19  -+ (black is winning)
$22  white is in zugzwang
$23  black is in zugzwang
$32  white has a development advantage
$33  black has a development advantage
$36  → (white has the initiative)
$37  → (black has the initiative)
$40  ↑ (white has an attack)
$41  ↑ (black has an attack)
$132  ⇆ (white has counterplay)
$133  ⇆ (black has counterplay)
$140  ∆ (with the idea)
$146  N (novelty)
```

I included symbols for all of the ones that are supported by my browser (chrome).  Hopefully someday the missing ones get added too...

The most common symbols are definitely the first handful, but the last four are also commonly used.

Comment: I don't think that $14-$17 are currently supported, when I tried those out they ended up as an empty square instead of the correct unicode symbol.

Comment: +1, Thank you for this answer. I was able to figure out a lot of them by trial and error. I will try to remember some bugs with the PGN viewer when using those symbols and will make a new post on Meta. Best regards.