# How do I insert a PGN?

Tags: support, pgn-viewer

I'm new to stack exchange, and I was wondering: how do I insert a PGN? I want to use them to show different openings, review moves, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The basic mechanism is described in the links in [this post](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/656/a-list-of-unknown-features-of-the-replayer).  I wish there was a way to put this in the "Help" section for [Chess.SE](https://chess.stackexchange.com), but I'm not sure if it's possible to add site-specific help information to individual sites.

(I know this is basically a link-only answer, but it doesn't seem to make much sense to me to recapitulate in this answer a bunch of info that's well described elsewhere.  I'm also not sure if the question itself is considered a duplicate question, because the question and answer I've linked is on Meta...)